# Linq Query join a table to a List<string> object to find any Strings not in table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a webAPI that receives a list of objects. Currently this data is passed to a stored proc as a data table object, but as the dataDump can hold 1000's of ResponseAPI records, this is proving a little slow.

So, I have started to look into the concept of using EF to take the load, pushing all changes in one go using a SaveChanges on the context.

```
var dataDump = new List<ResponseAPI>
{
    new ResponseAPI
    {
        Id= "1000",
        Code = "C15",
        value = "1976"
    },
    new ResponseAPI
    {
        Id = "999",
        Code = "C14",
        value = "1976"
    }
};
var step2 = from l in dataDump
            join p in Plants on new { X1 = l.Code } equals new { X1 = p.Code }
            join ps in PlantTypes on new { X1 = l.Code, X2 = p.Id } equals new { X1 = ps.Code, X2= ps.Id}
            where ps.TypeName == "Daisy"
            select new {
                Code = l.Code,
                Id = p.Id
            };
```

As far I can tell, this code is working, no errors are produced. What I am trying to obtain is a list of Id's from the dataDump that currently do not exist in the Plants table.

I have had some success using a different technique, but that only had the one table join.

```
 var step1 = dataDump.Where(s => 
                            s.Code.Any(
                            a => !context.Plants
                            .Select(x => x.Code)
                                       .Contains(s.Code)))
                                       .Select(s => s.Code)
                                       .Distinct()
                                       .ToList();
```

The first snippet "step2" is just doing a basic join between the tables, which works, but I am not sure how to achieve the not! on the joins.

The second snippet "step1" has a not! on the context which does the job of only returning the values from the dataDump what are not in the Plants table.

My perferred method would be step1, but I do not how to add the second join which links on two fields.

Comment: Since you are NOT selecting any values from the table "PlantTypes", how is that join even useful ? Maybe it's for a futur développement ? Because as shown, i'd say just don't join the seconde table... It's not used !

Comment: Why do you need the `join` on `PlantTypes`? (PS try `into pj where !pj.Any()` on the `Plants` join). (PPS in `step1`, is `s.Code` a collection?)

Answer (score 0):

```
var step1 = dataDump.Where(s => 

        s.Code.Any(a => !context.Plants.Select(x => x.Code).Contains(s.Code))

        &&

        s.Code.Any(a => !context.Plants.any(x => x.PlantTypes.Select(t => t.Code).Contains(s.Code)))

                        ).Select(s => s.Code).Distinct().ToList();
```

This might need some fix but I would like to know if it's really a one to many to many relationship between your entities.

Comment: To start with I have a SQL Server stored proc that has a data table as the only param. So I am trying to improve the performance. Within this proc, I have an update which takes the data from this input data table and joins it to two different tables. This is what I am trying to replicate.And yes you are correct, I am not selecting a value, so I have changed the code above accorindingly